# C++ logging library that allows HTML/CSS output?

Tags: c++, logging

i'm looking for a C++ library, like boost.log or pantheios that easily allows for html/css-formatted log output, maybe with some fancy jquery. i'm sure this can be done with boost.log, but i suppose in that case i'd have to spend days until understanding how to program one owns sink, programming and then debugging it.

i wonder if there is some library that already can produce a html log directly from c++. apart from this it must work cross-platform and support utf-16 (or something alike to allow for non-english output).

any good suggestions?

Comment: Writing a script to do post processing on the log would probably be reasonable?

Comment: a good idea, alas for now i need a c++ only solution-- writing a script is nice, but as it has to be 'consumer'friendly, i cannot want them to run a script over the output. besides, i'd have to test+debug the script, adding some extra development time.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this, though I've seen people reference it.  It has threading support and has an HTML layout class, not sure if the latter is sufficient.

[log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)

Comment: thanks for the tip, i did shy away from log4cxx for it is looking so deserted (the webpage currently even has some spam-links in it), but maybe i should take a look into its capabilities, didnt saw it has a htmloutput layer!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3297/HTML-logger-portable-and-thread-safe

Or, somewhat less robust--not easily portable--and something I haven't used, but with a slightly different feature set:

http://www.kikijiki.com/en/2012/01/10/cpp-html-log-class/

Comment: thanks for both links, but i have doubts using code that "was written in a weekend so don't judge it severely." The other logger unluckily is not thread-safe and windows only.

Comment: The written-in-a-day one has worked for my purposes, but you're right: it's definitely an example of "feature-rich, easy, and reliable: choose two". Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Comment: again, thanks, and you're right about my wishes ;) i just wonder if anyone else had that desire and programmed some kind of sink for boost or some other flexible library. maybe i should do that, if noone has ;)

Comment: If you want to do that, the code for the logger from the first link doesn't look too heinous. He puts a bit many static color etc. values inline as opposed to all in one place, but it's definitely workable if you wanted to modify/extend it. 

A more robust approach would be to use a templating engine for the HTML bits, and inject log data. Some C++ templating engines that aren't part of larger frameworks and could stand alone: http://ctpp.havoc.ru/en/, which I quite like, and http://teng.sourceforge.net/ which looks good but i haven't used.

Comment: very good idea, as i also wondered, if i also need a xml log. maybe cpp would help me here. very nice links, thanks again!